# how can we achieve object oriented concepts in java swing

Tags: java, oracle, swing

I'm developing a employee management system with oracle and java swing. and while writing code for it how to bring the key concepts of object oriented programming namely inheritance,encapsulation,polymorphism,data abstraction.Can you send me a sample program for it or explain how to achieve .Thanks in advance

Comment: sounds like you are giving us a college assignment..

Comment: Hi @YohanesKhosiawan许先汉 i have doubt in it

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/

Comment: Hi@Aditya i have dcveloped database in oracle and connected with java swing and i finished update delete insert search

Comment: Hi @YohanesKhosiawan许先汉 good help!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thought of giving a comment but I think this is too long to fit inside a comment.

Since it's an employee management system.
What type of inheritance is the most obvious?

`employee <- manager, normal staff, depends on which industry your EMS is for, they might have HR, PR, programmer etc..`

Encapsulation, how?

```
declare private fields for your classes and provided setter getter methods
```

Data abstraction

```
you can make your Employee an abstract class
```

Polymorphism

```
one simple way is to overide your superclass methods
```

It's really not that hard, you can also google for their definitions.

Comment: Encapsulation is not providing a 1:1 mapping between private fields and getters/setters. Not when the object has some logic, at least.